# Pandas dataframe multiple columns bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with multiple columns in a dataframe. My dataframe looks something like this.

```
Age      Index 1     Index 2     Index 3     Index 4
18-30    20.000000  0.000000    0.000000    5.000000    
31-40    27.807487  6.746195    2.694364    1.069519    
41-50    45.499022  6.849315    1.663405    3.228963    
51-60    41.176471  0.000000    0.000000    11.764706
```

Desired output
[image: Chart]

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Answer (score 1):

Create index by `Age` column (if necessary), then `rename` columns and last use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
d = {'Index 1':'Payment', 'Index 2':'Gender Focus', 
     'Index 3':'H&S General', 'Index 4': 'H&S Covid 19'}
df.set_index('Age').rename(columns=d).plot.bar()
```